# How do i alter the size of googles polymer-project paper-elements?

Tags: css, html, polymer, project

I want to alter the size of various paper-elements. Specifically i want to make the paper-toggle-button appear about ~twice as big, so fat fingers have it easy. What is best practice? (I hope it is easy css)

Thanks, greetings, 1 hug and see ya!

Comment: Have you looked at the docs? https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling

Answer (score 0):

Just give your paper element a class, and then in your custom-style section, give it the correct height/weight dimensions.  Hopefully that helps.